# Why does Microsoft SQL Server check columns but not tables in stored procs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Microsoft SQL Server seems to check column name validity, but not table name validity when defining stored procedures.  If it detects that a referenced table name exists currently, it validates the column names in a statement against the columns in that table.  So, for example, this will run OK:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        Col1, Col2, Col3
    FROM
        NonExistentTable
END
GO
```

... as will this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        ExistentCol1, ExistentCol2, ExistentCol3
    FROM
        ExistentTable
END
GO
```

... but this fails, with 'Invalid column name':

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        NonExistentCol1, NonExistentCol2, NonExistentCol3
    FROM
        ExistentTable
END
GO
```

Why does SQL Server check columns, but not tables, for existence?  Surely it's inconsistent; it should do both, or neither.  It's useful for us to be able to define SPs which may refer to tables AND/OR columns which don't exist in the schema yet, so is there a way to turn off SQL Server's checking of column existence *in tables which currently exist*?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is called deferred name resolution.

There is no way of turning it off. You can use dynamic SQL or (a nasty hack!) add a reference to a non existent table so that compilation of that statement is deferred.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
AS
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #Dummy (c int)

    SELECT
        NonExistantCol1, NonExistantCol2, NonExistantCol3
    FROM
        ExistantTable 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #Dummy)    


DROP TABLE #Dummy

END
GO
```

Comment: Which is; the non-checking of tables, or the checking of columns?

Comment: The non checking of tables. If all tables used in a statement exist then it is not deferred.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; why did you need to DROP TABLE #Dummy?  Aren't temp tables auto-dropped once the stored proc finishes?

Comment: @Jez - Yes they are. Just habit!

Comment: And for that matter, why create the Dummy table at all?

Comment: @Jez - In order to defer the name resolution for that statement. Obviously once you add the NonExistantCols you want the statement to execute without error.

Comment: Yes, but if you don't create #Dummy, and you just say "WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM NonExistentTable), it still defers resolution, doesn't it?

Comment: @Jez - Yes it defers resolution but you will never be able to execute it so why bother creating it in the first place!

Comment: +1 This really saved me when deploying via dacpac and a reference to an external DB that was planned to change was causing the deploy to fail. This works much better than dynamic sql, which the production system may not have permission to execute anyway.

Comment: @Jez and others: +1 Interesting idea. Though I would also recommend that when using this approach, to include a near-future clean-up step of updating this code to remove all references to `#Dummy` as it is just tech debt upon completion of the release / roll-out (getting in the way of maintainability).

Comment: **#Dummy** name could be not that obvious for this case. I prefer **#deferred_resolution_on** name.

Answer (score 0):

This article in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686.aspx) should answer your question.

From the article:

> When a stored procedure is executed for the first time, the query
>   processor reads the text of the stored procedure from the
>   sys.sql_modules catalog view and checks that the names of the objects
>   used by the procedure are present. This process is called deferred
>   name resolution because table objects referenced by the stored
>   procedure need not exist when the stored procedure is created, but
>   only when it is executed.

Comment: OK, that answers the 'how' but not the 'why'... as in, what is MS's justification for doing this?  It would be more useful if they did deferred name resolution on column names too (or that option were available).

Comment: Well SQL Server is taking validation as far as it can, right? If the table exists, check its columns. Otherwise, if the table doesn't exist yet, there's no way to check it's columns.

Comment: No... SQL Server could say, 'error.  table does not exist.'  It doesn't have to allow deferred name resolution at all.  On the other hand, it could realize that a column doesn't yet exist but defer resolution on it because you might go on to change the schema later.  Deferring table name resolution but not column name resolution just seems irritatingly inconsistent.

Comment: @Jez - You can get consistent behaviour by using `WITH SCHEMABINDING` this makes it consistent in the stricter direction though.

Comment: Yeah...it'd be nice to have the option, but as Martin said, we're SOL. Microsoft has said they'd consider putting the feature (or misfeature for that matter) up for requirements discussion since SQL Server 2000...progress...? =T

Comment: Came across this in the review queue and edited the relevant information in.