# Microsoft SQL Invalid Column Name Inside of Conditional Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

I am using a Database Update Script which works based on versions.  It has a section for each version following this basic format:

```
if (SELECT max(version) FROM DatabaseVersion) < x
BEGIN
/*CODE*/
INSERT INTO DatabaseVersion ....... (Current Version Number, Description of Change)
END
```

One of the old updates was to change column names.  Today, when I try to update the database again with this script, I am getting "Invalid column name" errors.  I have debugged, and found that the error is happening on a line that cannot possibly be executed (since the Database Version is already higher than the "x" value in that conditional statement).  I ran a SELECT query to test if that SELECT query would execute, and it does not.  This indicates to me that the code is being "checked over" by the SQL server before being executed, which means that the FALSE on the conditional statement does not prevent the server from reviewing that code, and subsequently giving me that error.

How can I prevent, or bypass this, without changing any of the update code (which follows the format above)?

Comment: try this `if (1=2) alter table add columnName int null` just before using it

Comment: There isn't a direct way.  You should update your update script.  Martin has a hacky way to do it, but I can't imagine this would work better for you than just fixing your script...: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315861/why-does-microsoft-sql-server-check-columns-but-not-tables-in-stored-procs/4315884#4315884

Comment: I'll take a look, but my script isn't broken, per say.  I need it to function the way I have programmed it, and I've never before heard of a language which throws non-syntax errors on a conditional statement when the condition evaluates to FALSE.  Also, can you explain the (1=2) alter table suggestion, Horaciux?

Comment: SQL Server validates schemas prior to execution, specifically columns.  It isn't executing any `IF()` statements to decide whether or not it should validate further....

Comment: I will need it to get executed when the version number is less than x.  The use case is: an update is sent to a company that has a year old version of this program.  When they get it, their version number will be less than x, in which case, the program will be in a state where the code is valid.  However, on my computer, the version number is greater than x,  so the program is in a state where this code is invalid (invalid column name).

Comment: Is there any way to tell the SQL Server to not evaluate a certain section of code if the table name is invalid, or at least suppress the exception so the script can still run?

Comment: You can try Horaciux's suggestion or Martin's that I linked above, but no there isn't a nice way (unfortunately).  Both Horaciux's and Martin's suggestions hinge on *tricking* SQL Server.  Martin's uses a fake temp table to bypass validation of his query (SQL Server can't validate a table that doesn't exist yet), and Horaciux's uses a 'fake' `add column` statement, intended to trick SQL Server into thinking that column might exist.  (But it never will be added, hence the 1=2)

Comment: Ah, I understand; in that case, it does do what I need it to.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, both statements did not work.  I am still having the same problem as before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap your code that does not compile in `EXEC ()`:

```
if (SELECT max(version) FROM DatabaseVersion) < x
exec('INSERT INTO DatabaseVersion ....... (Current Version Number, Description of Change)')
```

Here is a picture where exec has executed more than 128 characters of code:

[image]

And here is the link to the documentation: [EXECUTE-Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql)

[image]

Comment: Will this add any vulnerabilities or security problems?  The script is not accessible from the outside world once compiled.

Comment: This script concatenates NOTHING, it's executed as you wrote it, so what security problems you are talking about?

Comment: I know that the exec() can be dangerous, but since, as you said, it does not concatenate, you are correct in that it should be secure.  I will implement this now.

Comment: exec() is ran in a different security context than the current user and can be a flaw...limiting access or completely blocking the exec() ability is the usual solution, and if your access to that has been blocked then this won't work for you.  As a one time run, go nuts.

Comment: @Twelfth  >>>exec() is ran in a different security context than the current user<<< Really? And under which security context does it run???

Comment: @Brandon Dixon >>>I know that the exec() can be dangerous<<< If you are talking about sql injection you should understand how it works. If your application ASKS A USER to pass in "a value", for example for SELECT * FROM T WHERE FIELD = ... and you execute it dynamically concatenating user's input with the query, malicious user can pass not only a value, but something like DROP TABLE. Your code does not accept any user input, concatenates nothing, and does exactly what you put in EXEC.

Comment: I am receiving an error that the exec statement can only receive 128 characters.  Is this a problem with the parameter, as in, can I store the string in a variable and execute the variable, or is this a limitation I cannot get around?  I cannot split the code up into 128 character chunks, because some lines of code are longer than 128 characters, and cannot be split.

Comment: >>>I am receiving an error that the exec statement can only receive 128 characters<<< are you sure you are using SQL Server? There is no such a limit. Maybe you don't use correct syntax and try to pass identifier instead of command? Do you use parentheses after EXEC?

Comment: Thank you.  I believe my problem was actually with escaping, not with the 128 character limit.  I've fixed everything now, and it is working correctly!